# What does the term 'application signing' mean in Android?

Tags: android

Can anyone please elaborate what is app signing in android and why it is necessary to upload an app to android market? Also tell me what changes it make to the application package/apk file.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You sign your application with your private key so that ownership and the integrity of the APK can be verified.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Public-key_cryptography

https://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/app-signing.html

You might've noticed that in some cases a download has an associated md5 hash, that's a similar sort of thing although intended exclusively for verifying the integrity of the download.

In the old days, you checksummed your downloads against the provided hash just because your connection was lossy and crappy and files could get corrupted.

These days it's that and security.

One among many security concerns would be a nefarious actor taking over your Android Market account and uploading a hacked/virus-infected APK. Signing with a private key ideally reduces the odds this could happen successfully unless they've made off with your keys as well. By identifying you, via the keys, they're also protecting your users from the aforementioned scenario.

Answer (score -1):

App signing is required to identify the author.

Android system requires that all installed applications be digitally signed with a certificate whose private key is held by the application's developer. The Android system uses the certificate as a means of identifying the author of an application and establishing trust relationships between applications. The certificate is not used to control which applications the user can install. The certificate does not need to be signed by a certificate authority: it is perfectly allowable, and typical, for Android applications to use self-signed certificates.